# Сложение Series без NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Пример данных:

```
s1 = pd.Series(data = [1,1,1,1,1], index = ['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3', 'idx4', 'idx5'])
s2 = pd.Series(data = [2,2,2], index = ['idx2', 'idx4', 'idx5'])
```

При сложении

```
s1+s2
```

Получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это понятно, так как любой тип + NaN = NaN, но мне нужно, чтобы в отсутствующих индексах при сложении были значения из слагаемого, где эти значения определены, то есть, нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я делаю так: перевожу в DataFrame, добавляю недостающие колонки, fillna(0) и складываю -- это очень плохо, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, спасибо! То же самое и с датафреймами интересует, если в одном из df нет некоторых колонок, тоже в итоге получится NaN.

Comment: так, вообще, можно сначала сделать s2.combine_first(s1), а затем сложить по индексам исходного s2, но я уверена это как-то проще может делаться

Comment: а почему бы и нет `(s1+s2).fillna(s2.combine_first(s1))`

Comment: да-да, я этот вариант уже написала сама себе в ответе, но все равно спасибо)

Comment: а, не совсем так же, (s1+s2).dropna().combine_first(s1), поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Series:

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)

idx1    1.0
idx2    3.0
idx3    1.0
idx4    3.0
idx5    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Для DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4]}, index=[1,2,4,5] )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [11,12,13,14]}, index=[1,2,3,5])
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

    x
1   12.0
2   14.0
3   13.0
4   3.0
5   18.0
```

Comment: а, ну да, спасибо !))

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно изобретать велосипед

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Согласна, потому и спрашиваю, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, конечно
(s1+s2).dropna().combine_first(s1)

Comment: Зачем писать то, что уже написал автор вопроса в комментариях?

Comment: я и есть автор вопроса, продублировала свой ответ в комментарии, потому что другой пользователь дал в комментариях ответ, почти аналогичный
, не увидев мой)